# Strings and use of \

Tags: c#, string

I have stringBuilder & string class, storing a path:

```
StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
name.Append(@"NETWORK\MyComputer");
String serverName = name.ToString();  //this converts the \ to a \\
```

I have tried a number of things, but it always results in the string having \

Using `serverName.Replace("\\", @"\");` doesn't work, it leaves it as a \

`servername.Replace("\\", "\"");`  adds a `"` to the string, which is still not correct.

Please assist.

Comment: what are you trying to do? there is a lack of question marks in this "question"

Comment: I was attempting to create a connection string, however, it seems the issue wasn't the \\, but another issue, which I have just solved.  thank you for the assistance, never the less.

Comment: @Craig - you should mention what your answer is (or post an answer) rather than just saying "it was something else". Your question/answer may be of some use to someone in the future.

Answer (score 7):

If you are concerned at a single back slash being shown as a double back slash then don't be - that is simply the way it is shown to you in the debugger.

The back slash is a [special character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), that 'specialness' is turned off by doubling it up. Alternatively the `@` symbol can be prefixed to the string in source code which avoids having to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
name.Append(Path.Combine("NETWORK", "MyComputer");
```

In strings `\` is an escape sequence. So `\` in debugger will be `\\`

Acc.to MSDN

`Character combinations consisting of a backslash (\) followed by a letter or by a combination of digits are called "escape sequences." To represent a newline character, single quotation mark, or certain other characters in a character constant, you must use escape sequences. An escape sequence is regarded as a single character and is therefore valid as a character constant.`

`Escape sequences are typically used to specify actions such as carriage returns and tab movements on terminals and printers. They are also used to provide literal representations of nonprinting characters and characters that usually have special meanings, such as the double quotation mark ("). The following table lists the ANSI escape sequences and what they represent.`

Read [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code can be compiled. Because \ is an escape character, thus the string `"\"` will be wrong. The `@"\"` is right because the `@` (literal) has ignored that escape and tread it as a normal character.

See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)